# Query method to searchin related collection

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

```
public class Trader {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    public String name;
    public String title;
    public String email;
    public String phone;
    public String address;  

    @OneToMany
    public Set<Trader> customers;

}
```

I need an auto generated query method to search among customers names of a given trader.

Sql query is :

```
SELECT trader.name FROM trader WHERE trader.id IN 
(SELECT * FROM trader AS t 
INNER JOIN trader_customers AS tc ON tc.trader_id = t.id 
WHERE t.id = 'Trader ID')
```

Need somethin like

```
findInCustomersByName(@Param("trader") Trader trader, @Param("name") String name)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple JPQL like

```
"select t.customers from Trade t where t.name= :name"
```

It gives you a list of Trade Objects and then get names of the respective objects.

Comment: thanks for your answer but i want to search in t.customers